Scrollbar changes theme Power BI desktop and Power BI Web
I have a strange issue (Power BI Bug) My Scrollbars changes theme both in Power BI desktop and Power BI Web.  I did not have any elements below the visual. This issue may be caused by DARK MODE. if I save the report in light mode and upload without switching report tabs the scroll bar it render well enough.
Before clicking the visual Scrollbar looks dull.

sometimes like this...

after clicking the visual. theme changes a little


Suggest raising a support ticket or a bug to Microsoft on this.
